# Java multithreading 2nd thread waiting for 1st

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to information from a web API, user needs to see only first 1,000 registers and the rest (can be up to 120,000) must be stored in a local database. Getting the 120,000 registers take a lot of time, and only 1,000 not that much, so I need 2 threads, one for all and another for only 1,000.
As soon as the thread of 1,000 ends, the servlet should return to the front-end and the thread with all the information should continue working.

```
runnable R1 = new runnable( "Thread-1", user, parentQuery, Integer.parseInt(nodeId), overlaping);
runnable R2 = new runnable( "Thread-2", user, parentQuery, Integer.parseInt(nodeId), overlaping);
R1.start();
R2.start();
List<List<pat>> fList = R1.getLists();
List<List<pat>> fList2 = R2.getLists();
while(true) {
    if(R1.getState().equals("TERMINATED")) {
        notExpiredThread = fList.get(0);
        almostExpiredThread = fList.get(1);
        expiredThread = fList.get(2);
        break;
    }
}

while(true) {
    if(R2.getState().equals("TERMINATED")) {
        notExpired = fList2.get(0);
        almostExpired = fList2.get(1);
        expired = fList2.get(2);
        break;
    }
}
```

If I don't set the while, code immediately tries to get the lists from fList and fList2, even when thread is still running.

runnable getLists() only makes the request to the API.

Should I create the threads somewhere else?

Comment: You can use Thread.join() instead of while(true).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to be sure, but I *think* what you want is `Thread.join()`.

You don't have any code above that waits for a thread to finish, though your loop would be capable of doing that if structured a bit differently. But I think what you want is more like this:

```
runnable R1 = new runnable( "Thread-1", user, parentQuery, Integer.parseInt(nodeId), overlaping);
runnable R2 = new runnable( "Thread-2", user, parentQuery, Integer.parseInt(nodeId), overlaping);
R1.start();
R2.start();
R1.join();  // wait until R1 is finished.
// ... do whatever you want now that R1 is complete; R2 continues to run

// if you want to wait until R2 is done, you could join here, or just check its status.
```

I don't know that that's exactly what you want, and I have not included exception checking or anything else you might need for the call.